# C++ reverse a string recursively and getting Exception thrown : Access violation reading location

Tags: c++, string, recursion, exception

I wrote this function to reverse a string recursively:

ex-reverse.cpp

```
string reverse(string s, int n) {
  if (s.empty() == true)
    return s;

  int len = s.length();

  if (n <= len / 2) {
    return s;
  }
  swap(s[len - n], s[n - 1]);

  reverse(s, n - 1);
}
```

ex-main.cpp

```
void testReverse(string s) {
  string rev = reverse(s, s.length() - 1);
  cout << s << " | " << rev << endl;
}

int main() {
  string words[] = {"",       "a",      "aa",     "ab",     "aba",    "abc",
                    "abccba", "abcdba", "abcdea", "abcdef", "abcdefg"};
  int length = 11;

  cout << "REVERSE" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    testReverse(words[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

when trying to debug I'm getting this.[image]

I know that it's not something complicated but can someone explain to me why I'm getting this and maybe what would be a good solution to handle it?

Comment: Note that reverse() doesn't return value on all paths.

Comment: I don't understand isn't it supposed to do a swap and after that, I pass the new string to the reverse function and do it again until stopping condition it's reached.

Comment: Look at the last line in `reverse()`: `reverse(s, n - 1);`. After that has been executed, what will the function `return`? Nothing. So the program has undefined behaviour. Note 2: Using recursion for this is not a good idea. Given a really long string, you'll get stack overflow.

Comment: @AndreiCălugăr Did your compiler warn you that the `reverse()` function did not return on all code paths?  If it did, this is why you should not ignore warnings like that.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I didn't get any warnings regarding that.

Comment: @AndreiCălugăr Which compiler do you use? `g++`, `clang++`, MSVC (Visual Studio), something else?

Comment: @TedLyngmo the one that Visual Studio 2019 has.

Comment: Ok, then add the option `/W4`. It's the highest warning level. Not sure it helps but - it should :-)

Comment: `warning C4715: 'reverse': not all control paths return a value` -- That is the warning you should have gotten if you are using Visual Studio 2019, and this is at `/W3`, so it isn't even on the highest level.

Comment: As @PaulMcKenzie said: Demo without any `/W` used at all: https://godbolt.org/z/CQ-aqq. Is it possible that you've managed to hide the warning messages when compiling from within the IDE? I remember having to do something to get all the gory details from the compiler at one point.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I did set it to the highest level now and made and added return hen calling reverse( x, n -1 ) now the only thing I have to fix is that it doesn't swap the first characters in the string.

Comment: Perhaps editing this question changes it too much and accepting the answer you've got for this question and creating a new question with the updated code is the best option.

Comment: @TedLyngmo good idea

Comment: @AndreiCălugăr just to be sure, you write this only so that you have written a recursive reverse function once yourself and not because you need to reverse a string?

Comment: @t.niese I see where you're going with this :-) It's used in a palindrome tester - and `std::reverse`ing the string isn't even needed. `bool isPalindrome(const string& s) { return std::equal(s.begin(), std::next(s.begin(), s.size() / 2), s.rbegin(); }` should probably do it.

Comment: @t.niese I'm trying to do an assignment and that's why I have to implement the recursive reverse function. I will be used in other functions also. But one of the points it's to write that function first. I know it can be done in other ways also but I had to satisfy these constrains.

Comment: @AndreiCălugăr It is always a good idea to mention in the question that it is part of an exercise, in which you have to solve it that way. Otherwise, you risk that half of the comments are suggestions to solve it in a different way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always check what warnings your compiler is showing.

In case of your code it should show you a message similar to this (the exact message depends on the compiler):

```
warning: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths [-Wreturn-type]
```

or

```
In function 'std::string reverse(std::string, int)':
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

If your compiler does not show such a message then you should change the compiler settings to increase the warning level.

`warning: control reaches end of non-void function` tells you that your code can exit the function (which has a non-void return type) without returning anything, and that will result in undefined behavior, which could by anything. In your case a crash, which is the best case, in the worst case your application just stars to behave weirdly after that point.

So you need to change your last line from `reverse(s, n - 1);` to `return  reverse(s, n - 1);`

Comment: Thank you , I changed the compiler settings now and added the last line and seems to be working.

Comment: +1 about checking warnings.  Checking does not mean (just) make them go away.  They are telling the developer something that needs to be thought out.  I know too many programmers just fix the symptom (e.g. make the compiler happy so that it's a "clean build", like that is the actual goal) vs.  understanding their code and is the Warning telling them something they must consider in their logic also.

Comment: @t.niese thank for pointing that out, I'll make use of them from now on.

Comment: @AndreiCălugăr I just saw that you use VisualStudio, those flags were related to gcc and clang. In general: error messages are syntax error, that needs to be fixed to compile. Warnings are things that are suspicious and can lead to runtime errors, or the best case only some unexpected results. But you should always ensure that your own code does not have warnings, by checking why this warning occurs, what side effects it could have, and then fixing it properly.  This may be annoying at first, but the more you take care of it, the less you make such mistakes.